# Java Path2D.closePath not working correctly?

Tags: java, awt

I was baffled to learn that the `closePath` method of Java's `Path2D.Float` does not actually close the path correctly. The following code:

```
Path2D.Float p = new Path2D.Float();
p.moveTo(3, 3);
p.lineTo(10, 3);
p.lineTo(8, 5);
p.closePath();

PathIterator it = p.getPathIterator(null);

float lastx = 0;
float lasty = 0;
boolean first = true;
while (it.isDone() == false) {
    float[] coordinates = new float[2];
    int type = it.currentSegment(coordinates);
    if (first) {
        first = false;
    } else {
        System.out.println("Segment from "+lastx+", "+lasty+" to "+coordinates[0]+", "+coordinates[1]);
    }
    lastx = coordinates[0];
    lasty = coordinates[1];
    it.next();
}
```

produces this output:

```
Segment from 3.0, 3.0 to 10.0, 3.0
Segment from 10.0, 3.0 to 8.0, 5.0
Segment from 8.0, 5.0 to 0.0, 0.0
```

However, one would expect `closePath` to close the path to coordinates `3, 3`, as it states in the documentation:

> Closes the current subpath by drawing a straight line back to the coordinates **of the last moveTo**. If the path is already closed then this method has no effect.
>    (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/Path2D.html#closePath--)

Replacing `closePath` by `lineTo` to the starting coordinates produces the desired segments, however the segment type of the last segment this way does not equal `SEG_CLOSE`:
(https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/PathIterator.html)

```
Type: 0 // SEG_MOVETO
Type: 1 // SEG_LINETO
Segment from 3.0, 3.0 to 10.0, 3.0
Type: 1
Segment from 10.0, 3.0 to 8.0, 5.0
Type: 1
Segment from 8.0, 5.0 to 3.0, 3.0
```

Appending another `closePath` call again produces incorrect results:

```
Type: 0
Type: 1
Segment from 3.0, 3.0 to 10.0, 3.0
Type: 1
Segment from 10.0, 3.0 to 8.0, 5.0
Type: 1
Segment from 8.0, 5.0 to 3.0, 3.0
Type: 4 // SEG_CLOSE
Segment from 3.0, 3.0 to 0.0, 0.0 // <- not the correct coordinates!
```

Can anyone reproduce this, or otherwise explain what I'm missing if this is not a bug?

Additional info:
OS: Mac OS X 10.10.5
JDK: jdk1.8.0_92

Kind regards

Comment: I take it that it's also drawing incorrectly?

Comment: Look at the `PathIterator` Javadoc, and you'll have your answer.  To summarize, if the int returned equals SEG_CLOSE, no points are put into the array (hence, [0.0, 0.0], the default float values, comes back, as you notice and as is expected).  So to alleviate the issue, check the int return type of `currentSegment()`  https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/PathIterator.html

Comment: I see. I don't know about the drawing (but @Boann suggests it will be fine), because I'm not using the path for drawing purposes. I'm simply using it to test whether or not points are contained in the area with the path as a shape.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not saying it's intuitive (seems like SEG_CLOSE returning the points it's closing to would make sense...?), but the AWT can be like that sometimes. :)

Answer (score 1):

When you define a `Path2D` it stores, essentially, an uninterpreted list of the method calls that were used to define the path in the first place, so `closePath()` doesn't doesn't do any geometry logic. It records that `closePath()` was called, but doesn't store any additional points in the path's internal points array, because that's not necessary; code that iterates the path segments will be able to remember where the path started.

Likewise, [`PathIterator.currentSegment`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/geom/PathIterator.html#currentSegment-float:A-) says "`SEG_CLOSE` does not return any points" (since `closePath()` was not called with any points). Since it is not returning any points, you are printing out the default zeros that your `coordinates` array is initialized with.

If you're iterating the path manually for some purpose you'll need to handle each segment type separately, since they have different numbers of associated points. You can print out the path this way:

```
float moveX = 0, moveY = 0;
for (PathIterator it = path.getPathIterator(null); !it.isDone(); it.next()) {
    float[] c = new float[6];
    int type = it.currentSegment(c);
    switch (type) {
    case PathIterator.SEG_MOVETO:
        System.out.println("moveTo(" + c[0] + ", " + c[1] + ")");
        moveX = c[0]; moveY = c[1];
        break;
    case PathIterator.SEG_LINETO:
        System.out.println("lineTo(" + c[0] + ", " + c[1] + ")");
        break;
    case PathIterator.SEG_QUADTO:
        System.out.println("quadTo(" + c[0] + ", " + c[1] + ", " + c[2] + ", " + c[3] + ")");
        break;
    case PathIterator.SEG_CUBICTO:
        System.out.println("cubicTo(" + c[0] + ", " + c[1] + ", " + c[2] + ", " + c[3] + ", " + c[4] + ", " + c[5] + ")");
        break;
    case PathIterator.SEG_CLOSE:
        System.out.println("closePath() (back to " + moveX + ", " + moveY + ")");
        break;
    }
}
```

If you send the path to be drawn by a `Graphics2D` you don't need to worry about this; the renderer will handle it correctly. Likewise, all the hit-testing methods of the path work fine, as [they iterate the path](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8u/jdk8u/jdk/file/561c1038f71a/src/share/classes/java/awt/geom/Path2D.java#l541) the same basic way as you see above.

Comment: I see. I understood `closePath` simply added a `lineTo` to the coordinates of the last `moveTo`, and tagged it with a special segment type to indicate to other geom libraries that the path is closed (and is hence a shape with a surface of sorts). From what I understand, this is what it does in rendering, but not when iterating over the segments. So to solve my problem I can either inspect the segment type and manually translate SEG_CLOSE to a lineTo to the first coordinates, or just "close" my path with a lineTo instead of closePath, right? Thanks.

Comment: @Warkst If you're using the path's own `contains` methods for hit-testing, there is no problem. It already handles this correctly.

Comment: Besides hit testing, I'm also interested in the distance between any point and the shape of the path. For this, I thought I'd iterate over the segments, convert them to line2d instances, and use the ptLineDist method to find the closest distance to any point (as the minimum of all the distances to each of the segments). In this case, it's necessary the last segment returns the correct coordinates to correctly convert it to a line2d.